# How can I limit a generic data structure to allow only elements of a specific interface?

Tags: java, generics, interface, limit

Say I want to create a generic class for storing objects, but it shall only store objects that implement a specific interface. 
The interface goes something like this:

```
interface GenericSortedList<E> extends Iterable {    
   void add(E e);
   E get(String key);
}
```

Instances of GenericSortedList shall only be allowed to contain objects that implement the interface `Comparable`. How'd I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can introduce an upper bound on your type parameter `E`.

```
interface GenericSortedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Iterable<E>
```

Also make sure you pass `E` as the type parameter to `Iterable`, or else it will extend the raw form of the `Iterable` interface.

To make it more flexible, you can put a wildcard and a lower bound on the `E` inside `Comparable`.

```
interface GenericSortedList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends Iterable<E>
```

This way, a superclass

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>
```

and its subclass

```
class Bar extends Foo
```

can fit `E`'s restrictions.

Comment: Ah, okay, so the interfaces it extends also needs the parameter. Makes sense. The wildcard statement is also very useful! Thanks!

Comment: Edit: Nevermind. Found out I could add more interfaces with "&". I just expected a comma which didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Basically:

```
interface GenericSortedList<E extends Comparable> extends Iterable {    
   void add(E e);
   E get(String key);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that was easier than I though. However, shouldn't the list which is being iterated over have the "extends Iterable", since it's the list which is targeted in a foreach loop/iteration and not the object? 

So something like "GenericSortedList<E extends objectInterface> extends Iterable{...}"?

Edit: Yeah, that seems better :)